# How to melt a dataframe of 0 and 1 and keep only the 1s

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my original dataframe:

```
Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Variable 1 | Variable 2
-------------------------------------------------------
Blabla1 |   Hop1  |  Hip1   |   0        |   1
Blabla2 |   Hop2  |  Hip2   |   1        |   0
Blabla3 |   Hop3  |  Hip3   |   1        |   1
Blabla4 |   Hop4  |  Hip4   |   0        |   0
```

My objective is to put Variable 1 and Variable 2 in lines if they have 1 in it. For the above example, excepted result would be:

```
Label 1 | Label 2 | Label 3 | Variable   
------------------------------------------
Blabla1 |   Hop1  |  Hip1   | Variable 2
Blabla2 |   Hop2  |  Hip2   | Variable 1
Blabla3 |   Hop3  |  Hip3   | Variable 1
Blabla3 |   Hop3  |  Hip3   | Variable 2
```

There 3rd line is repeted twice since it has 2 variables and 4th line disapears because it has only 0s in it.

I've found a solution that make the job with `pandas.melt` function:

```
melt_DF = df.melt(id_vars=['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'], value_vars=['Variable 1', 'Variable 2'])
melt_DF = melt_DF[melt_DF['value'] == 1].drop(columns='value', axis=1)
```

My problem is that my DataFrame is way bigger and most of the values are 0 . Creating the first melt_DF uses too much memory before deleting most of the rows in the second line. Is there a way to apply the melt only on the 1s to save memory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try using `set_index`, `stack`, and `mask`:

```
df.set_index(['Label 1', 'Label 2', 'Label 3'], inplace=True)
df = df.mask(df == 0).stack().reset_index()
df
```

Output:

```
   Label 1  Label 2  Label 3     level_3    0
0  Blabla1    Hop1    Hip1    Variable 2  1.0
1  Blabla2    Hop2    Hip2    Variable 1  1.0
2  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3    Variable 1  1.0
3  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3    Variable 2  1.0
```

And, to do a little column renaming and cleanup to match expected output:

```
df.mask(df1 == 0).rename_axis('Variable', axis=1).stack().reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Label 1  Label 2  Label 3    Variable
0  Blabla1    Hop1    Hip1    Variable 2
1  Blabla2    Hop2    Hip2    Variable 1
2  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3    Variable 1
3  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3    Variable 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have mostly zeros and only 2 variables, then the following logic should be quite efficient:

1. Keep only the rows that have at least one nonzero entry
2. Apply the solution you already have

This can reduce the size of your melt in and output a lot so I hope it will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

#### `join`

```
cols = ['Variable 1', 'Variable 2']
data, idx = zip(*[(v, i) for (i, v), a in df[cols].stack().items() if a != 0])

df.drop(cols, 1).join(pd.Series(data, idx, name='Variable'), how='right')

   Label 1 Label 2 Label 3    Variable
0  Blabla1    Hop1    Hip1  Variable 2
1  Blabla2    Hop2    Hip2  Variable 1
2  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3  Variable 1
2  Blabla3    Hop3    Hip3  Variable 2
```